# Is `CreateProcess` really thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Lets suppose situation when we have multithreaded application that has to run some external executable on Windows. The best example if Apache that calls CGI script on multiple threads.

`CreateProcess` documentation doesn't contain any information about its usage limits. So, it is supposed to be thread safe.

Lets create program that will use `CreateProcess` to run `cl.exe` command in multiple threads. The only job the program does is creation of 100 threads, and each thread runs `cl.exe` and sleeps for 1 second. I run this program for 10 minutes, so it run `cl.exe` 600 * 100 = 60000 times. Usually `cl.exe` runs good, however, 25 times `CreateProcess` returned 0 and `GetLastError` returned 8. From Microsoft, 8 = `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`. It is impossible, because my system has 24 GB of memory and uses 40% of this memory only. So, the error looks wrong.

OK, now I run the same process on 1000 threads, and now almost all `CreateProcess` call results in fake `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`.

This problem disappears if we ensure that we call `CreateProcess` in single thread at each moment of time (I do it with `std::mutex`).

Does anyone know is `CreateProcess` supposed to be thread safe and is there more effective way to create child process in multithreaded application that using mutex to call `CreateProcess` on single thread only?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.aspx?G=2&ArtID=4598

Comment: CreateProcess is thread safe. Are you running a 32bit app? Alternatively, there's plenty of other resources that may be exhausted if you hit the system hard. And unless you have a _huge_ amount of cores spawning that many cl's will be counter productive.

Comment: This may also help explain some of the issues you might see with many threads or processes. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/

Comment: I use 64 bits Windows 7. The question is not about productivity, it is about thread safety. Productive or not, theoretically `CreateProcess` must work on any amount of threads if it is thread safe, and "out of memory" error when system uses 45% of its memory doesn't look like correct behavior.

Comment: Incorrect. Thread safety is _not_ the same as I can run a huge number of threads and it must work. I didn't ask about your OS, I asked about you app. What bitness is you app? 32 or 64?

Comment: There are limits to everything and you're hitting one or more of them with your usage pattern. It isn't all about physical memory.

Comment: Application is 64 bit one. System resources are very huge, and no one hardware resource is 100% used when fake error appears. I check CPU, memory, hard drive. They are OK and are not overloaded. `cl.exe` without parameters just writes fixed message and exits in a second or two.

Comment: OK for a 64 bit app virtual address space wont be an issue. Thats one of the 'limits' alluded to by @RetiredNinja which isn't specifically physical memory.

Comment: It might be interesting to paste a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing this issue. Alternatively, use task manager to show how many threads, handles, user objects, GDI objects, processes etc are active in your app/system at any one time - this may lead you in the right direction. And monitoring the CPU/Memory/Hard Drive in a naive fashion is very unlikely to help - its most likely to be some kind of internal limit you're hitting.

Comment: And one last thing - CreateProcess is asynchronous anyway. Its not worth spinning up a thread for each call. Just call them all on the same thread or at most create a few threads.

Comment: There is probably a limit to the number of process creation calls that can be occurring at one time.  You're probably hitting that limit, which is reported as "out of memory" (since an internal table or something is full).  You could try calling [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022(v=vs.85).aspx) after creating a process, or throttle your creation to not try to do too many at once.

Comment: For sure CreateProcess is thread safe.

Comment: You should check if you hit the commit limit with your many cl.exe calls. If you have 60k processes running where each commits 1MB you need 60GB of memory. That is most likely the reason for error 8. The other issue with 1000 threads is that if your app is x86 you will hit the address space limit of 4GB since each thread usually reserves 4MB of stack space.

Comment: I think your own process is running out of memory after creating so many threads. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx - "The default stack reservation size used by the linker is 1 MB.".

Comment: As I wrote above regarding memory: system uses 45% of memory only according to task manager; next, no one runs 60K processes in parallel; as i wrote, I use 1000 thread to run process 60 times (run/wait for exit/run next), so max 1000 processes exist in parallel. And also "out of memory" appears even when I run 100 threads (100 processes in parallel), such amount is normal for Windows x64.

Comment: For downvoters: I agree, may be we have to change this question from `Is CreateProcess really thread safe?` to `What are undocumented CreateProcess limits?`. However, I don't think that understanding of Windows undocumented limits "has no research effort, is unclear and not useful".

Answer (score 0):

You're mistakenly assuming all bytes in memory are alike, i.e. they form one big pool. This is simply incorrect on Windows.

The main division is paged pool versus non-paged pool. Paged pool stores code and data which can be paged to disk if necessary. Non-paged pool can't be paged to disk. For instance, essential parts of the OS that handle paging can't be paged to disk - how would you page them back in? Here, one pool can be empty while the other still has space.

Another limited resource is the RAM used for mappings between physical and virtual memory. Obviously, with all your processes, you're going to be using a lot of that. Each process has its own address space. Let's assume it's a 32 bits `cl` process; it has 4GB address space in the form of a million pages. Your 60K processes together take 60 *billion* pages of address space. And while quite a few of these pages are just shared copies of `cl.exe`, each of those pages needs a 64 bits pointer to physical RAM.

What you see here is a bit funny: you can have 60000*8 = 480.000 bytes of pointers to a single 4096 byte page. That's the sort of unusual situation that can cause simple memory statistics to be extra misleading. If you just count the 4096 bytes of actual content, you're underestimating the memory needed by about a factor of 100.

Comment: Does it explain that system goes out of memory with 55% free memory? Next, you didn't read what I write; no one runs 60K processes in parallel. 1000 ones max. 60K is how much such program will create during a minute; program runs process each second and waits for its exit. Even when I have 100 processes run in parallel, out of memory appears.